# Open file, rename file to variable and refer to file throughout macro using new name

Tags: excel, vba

I need to choose a file from a pop-up box, open it, then rename the file so I can activate it periodically in my macro without worrying about the file name being different each time the macro is run.

Comment: When you are opening the workbook, capture the result in a workbook variable: `Set wb = Workbooks.Open...`. Now you don't need to refer to it by name at all.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need or want to `Activate` or `Select` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for a thorough explanation why not and how to avoid doing so.

In your case, when you are opening the workbook, capture the result in a workbook variable:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...)
```

Now you don't need to refer to the file by name at all.